# Как спарсить информацию за скрывающимся элементом?

Tags: php, парсер, curl

С помощью cURL получается спарсить только первые 5 элементов на сайте, остальные элементы закрыты под кнопкой "Показать всё".

[image: скриншот]

Пытаюсь спарсить информацию с Яндекса https://yandex.ru/web-maps/covid19 слева во фрейме информацию.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно спарсить информацию, которая закрыта и для её появления нужно нажать на элемент ?

Comment: Нажать на элемент, посмотреть в панели разработчика что происходит. Возможно там идет запрос на какой-то урл, надо будет тоже туда сходить.

Comment: там выполняется JS скрипт

Comment: прежде чем нажать на кнопку открываете в браузере консоль разработчика вкладка network и увидите что там идет запрос на url https://yandex.ru/clck/jclck/  с кучей заголовков - их нужно все учесть